# lastInsertId(tableName_id_seq) returning :Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "tableName_id_seq" does not exist

Tags: mysql, postgresql, symfony, insert, doctrine

inserting data in my table in a foreach, and i need to have the last ID inserted.

Im inserting a first entity, get the Id and insert a child entity, linked with this ID.

Database POSTGRES - ENV Symfony 4

Code :

```
$conn = $em->getConnection();
//Here i do an Insert ( always an INSERT )
$Id = $conn->lastInsertId('tableName_id_seq');
```

This return  :
    Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "tableName_id_seq" does not exist

I feel like my sequence are not created in the DB
I do not close connexion before calling lastInsertID
It's Always un insert before lastInsertID

This Query:

```
select sequence_schema, sequence_name from information_schema.sequences;
```

Return 0 rows

Answer (score 2):

With `MySQL` you don't need to provide the `tableName_id_seq`

Can you just try `$Id = $conn->lastInsertId();`

Comment: Tried, this would return : Object not in prerequisite state: 7 ERROR: lastval is not yet defined in this session

Comment: Oh, on Postgres, ... hmmm, so `$conn->lastInsertId('tableName_id_seq');` should works if you do an `insert` before ...

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem ... Everything is 100% like the Doc, but yet cant make it works

Answer (score 0):

Well no way using lastinsertId(),
I found my way using

```
RETURNING id
```

in the Query, and then after the

```
$preparedQuery->execute()
```

i do a

```
$preparedQuery->fetchAll()
```